# Streaming quotes onto Excel

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to have streaming quotes in excel using python. Keep in mind this is the first time that I'm trying to learn python. I've been able to get the quotes off of the IexFinance API, and from there I get there data onto a CSV through Python, and I would make a Macro to refresh the CSV in excel every few seconds. However it seems that the csv takes a while to update and it's not as fluid as streaming quotes on other websites. So first of all, is there a simpler way to get the streaming quotes onto excel through python? And is there any way for me to have the quotes updated every second, or is excel or python delaying the update speed of the quotes?

```
amd.get_price()
import pandas
import pandas as pd
from iexfinanace.stocks import Stock
import csv
import time
batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
df=batch.get_price()
df.to_csv('stock.csv')

#loop
starttime=time.time()
while True:
    batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
    df=batch.get_price()
    df.to_csv('stock.csv')
    time.sleep(0.05-((time.time()-starttime) % 0.05))
```

Comment: What is awhile? Do you have a specific timeframe? Also, have you checked that you are actually not limited by iexfinance's API?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the csv once and then to update it, use pandas, xlwt, or any other modules like that

example with python:

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
from iexfinanace.stocks import Stock
import csv
import time
batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
df=batch.get_price()
df.to_csv('stock.csv')

#loop
starttime=time.time()
batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
df=batch.get_price()
df.to_csv('stock.csv')
while True:
    batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'])
    df=batch.get_price()
    df.to_csv('stock.csv')
    time.sleep(0.05-((time.time()-starttime) % 0.05))
    xl_spreadsheet = pd.read_csv(Location,header=None)
    xl_spreadsheet['{INSERT LOCATION}'].value = {batch insert for var of amd}
    xl_spreadsheet['{INSERT LOCATION}'].value = {batch insert for var of tsla}
```